# Count the clicks for short url using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a website for create a short url .I am facing the problem in count the clicks for the short url. I can fetch the short url from db and redirects to that particular website. Once its redirects that particular website short url clicks will be increased +1. But its not incresing. last day its self i am trying but i cant get the result.

This is my controller coding..

```
class Go extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('Select_model');
        }
    public function index(){
            $url_code = $this->uri->segment(1);
            // redirect the short url 
            $query = $this->Select_model->selectShortUrl($url_code);
            // update clicks for short url
            $update = $this->Select_model->updateShortUrl($url_code);

   }  
}
```

This is My model coding..

```
 // redirect the short url 
public function selectShortUrl($shorturl){
      $cx=$this->db->select('*')
                   ->from('url i')
                   ->where('i.shorturl',$shorturl)
                   ->get();
           if ($cx->num_rows() == 1) {
               foreach ($cx->result() as $row) {
                    $url_address = $row->fullurl;
           }
           redirect (prep_url($url_address));
         }
        else{
            redirect(base_url());
        } 

}

// update clicks for short url
public function updateShortUrl($shorturl){
        $cx=$this->db->set('clicx','`clicx`+1')
                   ->where('shorturl',$shorturl)
                   ->update('url');
        return $cx->result();
}
```

Comment: i think when you redirect url that time update count . your problem is redirect url  after you update count so count not will be update.

Comment: @HothiJimit thanks for ur comment... Have u know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mistake is

```
 $query = $this->Select_model->selectShortUrl($url_code);
            // update clicks for short url
            $update = $this->Select_model->updateShortUrl($url_code);
```

redirect url after increate number but that method can not call.

so you change below code in controller and model resp.

your controller

```
class Go extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('Select_model');
        }
    public function index(){
            $url_code = $this->uri->segment(1);
            // redirect the short url 
            $query = $this->Select_model->selectShortUrl($url_code);
            // update clicks for short url


   }  
}
```

your model

```
// redirect the short url 
public function selectShortUrl($shorturl){
      $cx=$this->db->select('*')
                   ->from('url i')
                   ->where('i.shorturl',$shorturl)
                   ->get();
           if ($cx->num_rows() == 1) {
               foreach ($cx->result() as $row) {
                    $url_address = $row->fullurl;
           }

           $this->updateShortUrl($shorturl);


           redirect (prep_url($url_address));
         }
        else{
            redirect(base_url());
        } 

}

// update clicks for short url
public function updateShortUrl($shorturl){
        $cx=$this->db->set('clicx','`clicx`+1',FALSE)
                   ->where('shorturl',$shorturl)
                   ->update('url');
        return $cx->result();
}
```

Comment: as per your comment the short url only redirect to long url but the clicks is not updated..

Comment: your table name check  your database not correct    which name used "url i" ya "url" ??? both name different ???.

Comment: its correct only i its like a object we can put any letters like that...

Comment: answer edit please check it its working in my system